# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: No one has been nominated yet. Who are our current moderators?

Comment: @JBH Current ones [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) plus any volunteers with enough points.  It looks like you have to self-nominate to become a candidate.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, Mason & Pete are the only two moderators left after the Monica Ciello fallout?  Ouch.

Comment: @JBH Double Ouch is more like it, since we lost [Caleb](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/30/caleb) and [Nathaniel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/21576/nathaniel-is-protesting), two "patriarchs" who have contributed a TON.

Comment: I think that makes a triple ouch! **El'endia Starman** is gone now also.

Comment: If you want to self-assess as to your candidate score before nominating yourself, I found the answer to the candidate scoring formula [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election/252643#252643).